# How to set and track a user's online status

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular with ui-router. I want to capture if a user is online or not to show the people they're connected to on the site their status. I looked into $stateChangeStart event and so on, but it doesn't seem to cover if the browser was closed.

What is the best way to set a user's status when they're in the app and change to offline when they leave?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Hmm, maybe have a regular Ajax call say "Hey, i'm still here!"?

Comment: Or websocket ping, or web worker that relays status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on Backend you use, for example there can be socket connection established and when dropped, server will know this. Or it can be just function which sends each minute one query to url and server write last_visit_datetime to user. Or cookie based solution.

Comment: Awesome. I'm using meteor so I can tell on the backend. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the `onbeforeunload` event on the `$window` service.

```
angular.module('app').controller('controller', [
            '$window',
    function($window) {
        $window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
]);
```